# Getting array(0) { } when i should get results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying for the last few days but I just can't get this figured out. I have a filter page where the user can select the start_date, end_date, client and paying_status. Client and paying_status are referencing to the main service table.

I even echo all the $_POST and get the right inputs but my SQL query isn't producing any results. When I run the same query on my database, I get the right results. I don't see any errors or I'm getting blind over my own mistakes after all these days.

```
<?php
include "../controller/session.php";
include "../controller/pdo.php";


$submit = isset($_POST["filter-submit"]) ? $_POST["filter-submit"] : "";
$date_start = isset($_POST["date_start"]) ? $_POST["date_start"] : "";
$date_end = isset($_POST["date_end"]) ? $_POST["date_end"] : "";
$client = isset($_POST["client"]) ? $_POST["client"] : "";
$payed = isset($_POST["payed"]) ? $_POST["payed"] : "";

echo $date_start . "<br>" . $date_end . "<br>"  . $client . "<br>" . $payed . "<br>";

if ($submit == "Filter") {

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from service where(date BETWEEN ':date_start'AND ':date_end') AND clientId=:client AND paying_status=:payed;");
    $query->bindParam(':date_start', $date_start);
    $query->bindParam(':date_end', $date_end);
    $query->bindParam(':client', $client);
    $query->bindParam(':payed', $payed);
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    var_dump($results);

}
```

2019-01-01 
2019-07-03 
1 
1 
array(0) {}

Above are the $_POST inputs and the empty array. I don't know where to watch anymore.

EDIT: 
**SELECT * from service where(date BETWEEN '2019-01-01'AND '2019-07-03') AND clientId=1 AND paying_status=1;**
This works fine on my database.

EDIT 2: Updated code. Still doesn't work.

```
if ($submit == "Filter") {

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from service where(date BETWEEN ':date_start'AND ':date_end') AND clientId=:client AND paying_status=:payed;");
    $query->bindParam(':date_start', $date_start);
    $query->bindParam(':date_end', $date_end);
    $query->bindParam(':client', $client, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':payed', $payed, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    var_dump($results);

}
```

EDIT 3:

```
if ($submit == "Filter") {

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from service where(date BETWEEN :date_start AND :date_end) AND clientId=:client AND paying_status=:payed;");
    $query->bindParam(':date_start', $date_start);
    $query->bindParam(':date_end', $date_end);
    $query->bindParam(':client', $client, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':payed', $payed, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    var_dump($results);

}
```

This works! Can someone explain why i sometimes need to execute the query and sometimes I just can fetch the data with fetchAll or just fetch? When do i need to execute and when can I just fetch? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the query that you have executed against the database? (that showed results)

Comment: isnt there a $query->execute() missing ?

Comment: What @FatFreddy said^ and you should add `PDO::PARAM_INT` to `$client` and `$payed` as 3rd param to `->bindParam`. You probably dont need the `''` quotes around `:date_start` and `:date_end`, PDO will automatically quote them as they are of type `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Comment: When I add PDO::PARAM_INT - same happens. When i add below $query-execute(); - I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in...

Comment: @svrdoljak Can you show your updated code? (In the best case with all changes mentioned above)

Comment: It's in the EDIT 2. This produces the PDOExeption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the '..number of bound variables ...' error because as @Xatenev says you don't need to quotes around your place markers.  What you are asking PDO to prepare is the string `'...BETWEEN :date_start AND ...`  i.e. it looks for a date with  STRING VALUE OF ':date_start' which presumably doesn't exist, rather than looking for a date value with the value of `:date_start`. 
If should look like this:

```
from service where(date BETWEEN :date_start .....
```

just to expand slightly, the actual error then occurs because you try to bind the values for each of the quoted placeholders, but PDO cannot see these placeholders at all, as all it can interpret are some strings you have added and two placemarkers

If you remove your quotes then it no longer sees this as a string and will view it as the place marker as intended

UPDATE -

Re OPs comments about not quite understanding, imagine you have a variable `$values`

$values[] contains 'jam','bread', or 'peanut butter' depending on the input.
So you want to insert into a table called sandwich_parts and you create a query based on the input (or selection, or loop for whatever)

```
foreach($values as $value){
    $q1->prepare("INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values (':value'));
    $q2->prepare("INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values (:value));
    $q->bindValue(':value',$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

this would be sent to mysql on execute() as

```
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values (':value')
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values ('jam')
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values (':value')
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values ('bread')
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values (':value')
INSERT INTO sandwich_parts (part) values ('peanut butter')
```

because the first insert always reads the string ':value' whereas the second sees the place marker and binds the parameter, as such you would get errors for the first query each time because it cannot see a placeholder to bind the value to

I hope that helps your understanding a little, basically, you don't need to quote placeholders that is what the binding process is for

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now. I put the answer in EDIT 3. Can you maybe explain the execute question I put in the EDIT 3? Thanks a lot!

Comment: not without some example code, you're probably best to search for that question, or post a new question.  I would hazard a guess (but a very cursory guess) that you are when you think you aren't executing a query you are using ->query("select...etc") rather than preparing a query and binding values

Comment: thanks anyway! I'll do my research :) But it's still a little confusing why do I need to remove the quotes.

Comment: @svrdoljak please see updated answer for a bit more explaination